# SQL Server Delete Rows from Table leaving the record with the Max CreationDate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete the older records from the table based on creation date,leaving the latest one

attempted SQL,but did not work.

```
 SELECT *
 --DELETE L
 FROM ItemPriceListMap L
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT ItemPriceListUID3,MAX(CAST(CreationDate as DATE)) MaxDate
 FROM ItemPriceListMap
 GROUP BY ItemPriceListUID3
 )M ON L.ItemPriceListUID3 = M.ItemPriceListUID3 AND CAST(L.CreationDate as DATE) = M.MaxDate
 WHERE M.ItemPriceListUID3 IS NULL
```

The view of the mapping

```
SELECT I.Description,ipl.UnitListPrice1,iplmp.VatMRP,iplmp.CreationDate FROM ItemPriceListMap iplmp
INNER JOIN ItemPriceList ipl ON iplmp.ItemPriceListUID3 = ipl.UID
INNER JOIN Item i ON ipl.ItemUID = i.UID
ORDER BY I.Description,iplmp.CreationDate
```

[image]

EDIT:

More Sample Data[image]
Using this SQL

```
SELECT I.Description,iplmp.ItemPriceListUID3,iplmp.CreationDate FROM ItemPriceListMap iplmp
INNER JOIN ItemPriceList ipl ON iplmp.ItemPriceListUID3 = ipl.UID
INNER JOIN Item i ON ipl.ItemUID = i.UID
ORDER BY I.Description,iplmp.CreationDate
```

so after I execute the delete command the highlighted row should be left in the table(yellow),highlighted in blue is the same Item

Comment: If you use ROW_NUMBER you can partition by ID and order by your date and then delete the rows with a number larger than 1

Comment: Will you please try my answer below ?

Comment: As @Allan S. Hansen has commented, you can use sql server windows functions to solve such problems. But for that you need to first know the candidate keys (column or combination of columns, data that can uniquely define your data you need to operate). You mentioned CreationDate is your candidate key but you just mentioned there are duplicates for this also.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: You can use your own query by doing some simple changes as below, you have to join as `<>` with the `max date` so it will not delete that record, only delete others which matches `ItemPriceListUID3 and <> MaxDate`

```
 SELECT *
 --DELETE L
 FROM ItemPriceListMap L
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(CAST(CreationDate as DATE)) MaxDate
            FROM ItemPriceListMap
            ) M ON CAST(L.CreationDate as DATE) <> M.MaxDate
```

Comment: I think you have unique `ItemPriceListUID3` if so then we can't group by it. We have group the field in which basis we are not deleting the max date or we have to `delete all except` one `max` from the whole table ?

Comment: okay that sound's fine,could you edit and post your sql,I'll check and let you know

Comment: This shows almost all the rows in the table (Total No of rows : 2296),your query shows 2295

Comment: Almost all but not all so you want that, it will delete all except one that is not returning in the select ?? if not then please post sample data for more clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133626/discussion-between-suraz-and-pathum-anjana).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE L
FROM ItemPriceListMap L
WHERE CreationDate <> (SELECT MAX(CreationDate) MaxDate 
                       FROM ItemPriceListMap LL
                       WHERE L.ItemPriceListUID3 = LL.ItemPriceListUID3)
```

Note : Take backup of your data first.

Comment: Select?? you mean to say above script deleted all records

Comment: Yes I replaced DELETE with Select before executing it but it did not return any rows,still confused why query wont work even the below answers

Comment: There are some rows with the same creation-date as well,is it the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE and a row_number

```
with CTE as
(
select a1.*, row_number() over(
                               partition by ItemPriceListUID3  -- remove this if you don't need the grouping
                               order by CreationDate desc) as R_ORD
from ItemPriceListMap a1
)
delete
from CTE
where R_ORD > 1
```

Comment: Tried 0 rows effected

Comment: @PathumAnjana Did you try without the partition?

Comment: I used your query before executing the SQL that was written by me(on a new backup),its still the same (537 rows deleted),but still the same issue is there